# Problems in mounting external disks for wine and virtualbox

Tags: disk-management

I am obliged to mount theses disks,( that i am using as storage with wine app , or virtualbox ) manually by clicking on them in the file browser.any other method does not work.i tried to modify the mount options with gnome-disks they appear mounted then in the file browser , but are still inaccessible in wine or virtualbox.Any solution to make it auto at startup?Thank you, coming from Mint17.3 and i love this distro...
Using Loki stable

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in putting this in the startup files:
udisksctl mount -b /dev/s[whatever, a1,a2,b1...etc].

System settings , Applications>Startup> + type in a custom command...Again , love this distro!